# The answer may hide if it's genuine

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

You never stop trying to tear me apart
Without a thought, not a care in your heart.

Sometimes you stab me with iron or steel
I just hug in return, although I'll never heal

I know, I know, you just want my support
Which I will provide, with no retort.

You used to scare kids with me back in the day
At least now you can't - it's no longer okay.

All tightened up, I wait in suspense
I cannot relax, I'm constantly tense.

My only relief in a day so bleak
Is when you leave for a second to go take a leak

When you're formal and proper, I'm stressed to the max
I want this to end, can you cut me some slacks?

Hint:

> I hate owls! Wait... no... that doesn't look right.

Comment: In my opinion the take a leak and the scare kids no longer okay lines were too much information.

Comment: @Goinghamateur ah, you are probably right. My first two riddles I felt were too obscure, so I tried to make my next two more obvious and maybe overcompensated. I'll find a happy balance eventually :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is below in spoilers

> a belt

You never stop trying to tear me apart
Without a thought, not a care in your heart.

> Can't say I quite get this, but may refer to constant pressure against a tight belt. Stolen from Dan Russell's answer: Tearing apart is taking it off. I guess the you never stop trying part threw me for a belt loop.

Sometimes you stab me with iron or steel
I just hug in return, although I'll never heal

> you can puncture new holes if a belt is too loose. Hug is wearing the belt. And I suppose just putting the belt on could entail stabbing in a simpler form, but the heal made me think in the creation of holes.

I know, I know, you just want my support
Which I will provide, with no retort.

> it supports your pants

You used to scare kids with me back in the day
At least now you can't - it's no longer okay.

> Beating kids is bad, mmkay

All tightened up, I wait in suspense
I cannot relax, I'm constantly tense.

> Once more the belt is tight, with a possible reference to their brethren suspenders.

My only relief in a day so bleak
Is when you leave for a second to go take a leak

> Undo the belt to take a leak

When you're formal and proper, I'm stressed to the max
I want this to end, can you cut me some slacks?

> Slacks do be pants you would wear a belt with. And when you are trying to look fancy you must be prim and proper entailing a most vigorous tightening of belt lest gravity aims to pants you with much impropriety.

The answer may hide if its genuine:

> Specifically it may cowhide if it is genuine, or be made from leather.

The hint

> I hate owls! Wait... no... that doesn't look right.
>  Working on it...

Comment: You are certainly correct! And you are right in your answers. Your first guess in the ones you are unsure about (first two) is exactly what I had in mind. Can you guess the title and the hint?

Answer (score 1):

You could be a

> belt.

You never stop trying to tear me apart
Without a thought, not a care in your heart.

> Every day you "tear" the belt to take it off.

Sometimes you stab me with iron or steel
I just hug in return, although I'll never heal

> The metal (iron/steel) clasp fits through a hole (stabbed) that is permanent.

I know, I know, you just want my support
Which I will provide, with no retort.

> A belt supports you by holding up the pants.

You used to scare kids with me back in the day
At least now you can't - it's no longer okay.

> Many use a belt to threaten corporal punishment, which is increasing frowned on by modern society.

All tightened up, I wait in suspense
I cannot relax, I'm constantly tense.

> Your belt is tense all day since that is its purpose.

My only relief in a day so bleak
Is when you leave for a second to go take a leak

> When you visit the bathroom, your belt gets a break.

When you're formal and proper, I'm stressed to the max
I want this to end, can you cut me some slacks?

> "Slacks" = pants!

Comment: There is no doubt in my mind this is the answer. But I'm frequently wrong. :>)

Comment: You are right, good sir! Unfortunately, hamateur was first, and a couple of his answers were closer to what I had in mind.